# Angular how to disable the screen when calling web service

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am new to **Angular** , this looks like a simple question but I couldn't find an  answer when googled it.. when I call a web service that takes a few seconds I have a spinner displayed but I want that all the screen will be disabled ( like a gray screen -something like I see on popup messages ) 
any ideas? I want this to work also when I have more than one component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place a `div` on the site and apply the following CSS to it. Then you can toggle if with *ngIf (set it visible at the start of the request and hide it after it finished):

```
<div class="disable-background" *ngIf="toggleLayer"></div>

.disable-background{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: #2d2d2d;
   opacity: 0.8;
   z-index: 998;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

What it does is that it lays a gray layer above the actual screen which is a bit transparent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ngx-spinner`. It is very easy implementation. You can check here -https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner.

Comment: also works perfect - thank you !! I will use this solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating some transparent image and that spans over whole page and make it show when your call to other web service is processing and later hide it... it will in addition to you gif